# jQuery Remove Div Based On Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i would like to remove/hide a li based on the content inside it, is this easy to do?

eg. the code below: if span#type has no content then li.grouping should be removed or hidden.

```
<li class="grouping"><span class="desc">Options:</span><br /><span id="type"></span></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("li.grouping:has(span#type:empty)").remove()
```

It would seem to make more sense if `type` were a `class`, rather than an `id`, as there should only be one element with a given `id` on the page. In that case:

```
$("li.grouping:has(span.type:empty)").remove()
```

Comment: sorry brain, almost perfect. the page errors in the case that span.type isn't empty. can we address this? i'm placing the code just before the closing </body> tag.

---
$("li.grouping:has(span.type:empty)") is null
---

Comment: Hmm. It works fine for me using jquery 1.3.2 in Safari 4 beta and Firefox 3.0.5. http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/jquery.html

Comment: Note also that placing the code at the end right before the </body> tag is not ideal; instead, you should use $(document).ready(). For example: http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/jquery2.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
if ($("span#type").text() == "") {
    $("li.grouping").hide();
}
```

Comment: This would hide all "li.grouping" if only one span anywhere was empty.

Comment: one span? or one span of class type? I assumed that the page will have only one 'span#type'